# Redirect dynamic routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I redirect

```
get '/directory/:alphabet' => redirect('/directory/:alphabet/1') , :constraints => { :alphabet => /[A-Za-z#]/}
```

This throws an error about alphabet. How do I use the value that I get ?

Answer (score 2):

See "dynamic segments" under http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Use %{alphabet} to read the value from the source

```
get '/directory/:alphabet' => redirect('/directory/%{alphabet}/1') , :constraints => { :alphabet => /[A-Za-z#]/}
```